# Pass block of text from webpage to perl script and then back to web

Tags: html, perl, cgi

I am trying to do the following.

Take a block of text that a user inputs in a TEXTAREA FORM from a website and pass it to a perl/cgi script that adds the line number before each line.  So for example:

```
diet coke
potato chips
gelato
```

would become

```
1 diet coke
2 potato chips
3 gelato
```

I know how to pass a single value or a bunch of values to a perl script, but when I try to do a foreach (@array) to add a line number it doesn't work.  Wondering how to do this.

My html file is

```
<HTML>
<BODY>

<FORM ACTION="/cgi-bin/splitfoods.pl">
  <P>What did you eat today? <BR><TEXTAREA NAME="value" ID="value" style="width:900px;height\
:700px;background-color:#FFF8DC;font-size:20px">
    </TEXTAREA>

<P><INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Submit">
</FORM>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

and the cgi file is (from matthewh)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI;
use CGI qw(:standard);


$query = new CGI;

@foods = split('\n',$query->param("value"));


# -- HTML STUFF --
print header;
print start_html;
for($i=1; $i<=@foods; $i++) {
    print "$i @foods[$i-1]";
    print "<br>";
}
print end_html;
```

request looks like

```
cgi-bin/splitfoods.pl?value=diet+coke%0D%0Apotato+chips%0D%0Agelato
```

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to add `$query = new CGI;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@foods = split('\n',$query->param('food'));

for($i=1; $i<=@foods; $i++) {

   print "$i @foods[$i-1]\n";

}
```

Comment: please see my full code above.  for some reason getting 500 server error.  file is executable so not sure what the error is

Comment: Can you check the error log? It will tell you the reason for the 500 error.

Comment: [error] Can't call method "param" on an undefined value at /var/www/cgi-bin/splitfoods.pl line 5.
[error] Premature end of script headers: splitfoods.pl

Comment: See my comment to your original question

Comment: now error is malformed header from script. Bad header=1 diet coke: splitfoods.pl

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit cleaner and less likely to breakdown on edge cases. Plus the numbering is HTML instead which is more natural for web. You really should read the entire document for [CGI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI) and always start code with warnings and strict on.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
no warnings "uninitialized";
use CGI ":standard";

# Scalar/array context matters with param()!
my $food = param("value");
my @foods = split /\n/, $food;

print
    header(),
    start_html(),
    ol(li( \@foods )),
    end_html();
```

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a way for me to include a php header in the perl file output using <?php include = "name.php" ?> .  How do I get the cgi script to include a splash header or image?  Thanks

Comment: @racket99: Really, if you’re already running PHP, there’s no
reason to do this as Perl. I personally prefer Perl but PHP is
easy and powerful for CGI. If you feel you must, you can run PHP
from Perl with the module [PHP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PHP). If you want to do more with Perl CGI, it will do anything you want, just check the doc. I do recommend learning something like [Template](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Template) instead. CGI is a nice Swiss Army knife but it’s not ideal for “serious” code.